# Any Idea how to get rid of those shading issues?

Tags: mesh, geometry

I am currently working on a knife but get some weird shading on the Blade.

I am using a edgesplit modifier with sharp edges on the model.

I think the cause of the problem is that on the one side the vertices are all aligned to the same x coordinates and on the other side every vertex has a different x coordinate (see last picture).

If anyone has an idea how to fix the shading/make it less obvious please let me know.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Delete the half of the mesh that's giving you trouble.  add a mirror modifier with the axis set to x.  apply the mirror modifier.  hopefully this correct your shading errors.

I hope this helps :)